# Access style resource defined in library project

Tags: android

I have something like this in my library project. I want to use that custom defined theme in my concrete project but Im not able to reference it.How can I achieve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="MenuDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did for workaround for now is: Im setting the theme not in the manifest file instead of that Im setting it before setContentView method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(package_library.R.style.MenuDialog);
}
```

Comment: Still using this workaround? Or maybe you've found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm still using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for this, if I understand your question correctly

Use this:

Create theme in style.xml file

```
<style name="Theme.SettingsBackground" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

and then in manifest file use:

```
<activity android:name=".Settings" android:theme="@style/Theme.SettingsBackground"></activity>
```

Do this for all sub activities which you want.

Comment: This if fine if it's in the same project.But I want to define theme in library project and use that theme in sub projects.